# Transfer Wordpress intranet site from my pc to the company local server

Tags: migration, localhost

I'm developing an intranet site with WordPress, and I'm hosting it locally using XAMPP (running on my office PC).

Can someone tell me step by step how can I:

1. Transfer the intranet site from my PC to the local server of my company.
2. Make it accessible for the company employee (I already started to create accounts for every employee).

Answer (score 0):

To push from your localhost to your company's server, I'd suggest using a database migration plugin. It will take care of the URLs for you, including serialized URLs which are easy to miss if you try to edit the db with a text editor.

To make it accessible other than WP logins, there are plugins available that will work with LDAP and other types of single sign-ons. Browse through the WP plugin repository for a variety options, depending on what type of system you are using to log in.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the [WP Clone plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/) to move sites from development to live. You install the plugin on source and target sites (plain vanilla WP install on target, since it will be overwritten), then backup on source and restore to target.

Works every time I use it, and is simple to use. Of course, you could copy all content, then run some SQL scripts to fix things, but the plugin has worked well for me.

It will copy themes, plugins, databases, and adjust URLs for the new place. It will also overwrite all user accounts, so you will have to log in with your 'source' admin account after cloning.